# SOAP issue after installing SUPEE-6788

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, cron, patches

We are running Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 and after installing SUPEE-6788 we always get this error when running Magento cron.sh

So, when following command runs

```
/bin/sh /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/cron.sh
```

We get this error, and it was not there before installing SUPEE-6788

> PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://www.mage-world.com/api/soap/?wsdl' : Extra content at the end
>   of the document  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/app/code/local/MW/Mcore/Helper/Data.php
>   on line 907

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly `MW_Mcore` module is doing. Looks like it tries to make SOAP V1 call to another Magento instance (https://www.mage-world.com/api/soap) and fails to initialize SOAP client with https://www.mage-world.com/api/soap/?wsdl because for some reason this WSDL is wrapped into `<html/>` and thus is not a valid WSDL document.

Contact owners of https://www.mage-world.com/api/soap/?wsdl, seems to be an issue on their side.